# Including block templates under different subdirectories

Tags: templating, matrix

How do I include block types that don't all sit under the one directory? My folder structure:

```
 - images
  - _blockName.html
 - mockups
  - ...
 - text
 - special
```

How I'm currently including the blocks (which isn't working):

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for block in entry.widgets %}
        {% include "widgets/_" ~ block.type ignore missing %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

How do I let craft know to look under each subdirectory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could get unwieldy if you have too many subfolder options, BUT... You CAN supply a list of templates to Twig's [`include`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) tag. Twig checks each option, and includes the first template in the list that exists:

```
{% include
   [
    '_widgets/_images/_'  ~ block.type,
    '_widgets/_mockups/_' ~ block.type,
    '_widgets/_text/_'    ~ block.type,
    '_widgets/_special/_' ~ block.type
   ]
   ignore missing
%}
```

*(The `ignore missing` tells Twig to fall back to rendering nothing if none of the templates exist. Otherwise it would throw an exception. A popular alternative is to have a default fallback template as the last item in the list.)*

Bonus 2¢: I think it's good practice to keep include templates in hidden folders (i.e. `_widgets/` instead of `widgets/`) — to signify to yourself and others that the directory does not match with a public route, and that its contents are never meant to be displayed directly.

Comment: Thanks for the Bonus 2¢ - small stuff like that is handy to know.